API POST Request using HttpClientInterface
I am trying to do a POST request to an API using Symfony HttpClientInterface. But I am struggling as it always throwing 400 error. But when using cUrl it is working fine.
$data = [
        'parameter1' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter2' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter3' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter4' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter5' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter6' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter7' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter8' => 'xxxxx'
    ];

$postData = http_build_query($data);
            $ch = curl_init($URL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ]);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

Symfony by usnig HttpClientInterface (not working)
$response = $this->tokenClient->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ],
    'body' => [
        'parameter1' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter2' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter3' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter4' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter5' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter6' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter7' => 'xxxxx',
        'parameter8' => 'xxxxx'
    ]
]);


Anyone has an idea why it's not working with HttpClientInterface and how can I make it work?

Do you have access to the API's log? My first suggestion would be to look there, and see if there's more info beyond just the general 400 error.
